# How can I read the property in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

```
var stats = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
for (index = 0; index <= top; ++index) {
    console.log(stats[index]);
}
```

**Return object:**

```
Object {nick: "Okorok", uniq: "STEAM_0:0:XX", teamkill: 4, damage: 619592, deaths: 1727…}
```

**How do I read a property?**

If I try `"console.log(stats[index]['nick']);"`, I have an error: `"Cannot read property 'nick' of undefined "`.

Comment: It looks to me like `stats` is an array of things. Maybe not all of them have a field called `nick`? Alternatively, maybe you've got the array size wrong. Instead of `index <= top`, you should probably have `index < stats.length`.

Comment: [my full code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xTuHL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if stats is an **Array of Objects or just a simple Object**.

If this is just a simple Object, so you directly use:

```
console.log(stats['nick']);
or 
console.log(stats.nick);
```

Ok, if it is **Object with Objects** try this:

```
for ( key in stats)
{
    console.log(stats[key].nick);
}
```

A sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/2d6bb/3/

Comment: oh. i have object of Objects

Comment: Your welcome. 
Correct your jsfiddle to:
if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var stats = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
 
    for (var key in stats) {
        console.log(stats[key].nick);
    }
    
   }

Comment: No, don't correct the jsfiddle. That's just confusing for people reading it in the future. I just posted that the jsfiddle was different from the question, then realised I had to edit my post. If people want to know the correct answer, they can read it here, under "Answers".

Comment: A problem with this answer is that you can get the output in any order, whereas the way you had it before, if it had worked, would have given them in numerical order. I don't know whether you care about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have somrthing like an array of objects, like:

```
stats = [{},{},{},...];
```

if it is so you can do this:

```
var stats = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
for (var index = 0; index<stats.length;index++){
    for (var key in stats[index]) {
        console.log(stats[index][key]);
    }
}
```

and if not, it would be an object of objects, like:

```
stats = { "stat1": {}, "stat2": {}, "stat3": {}, ...];
```

then you can do this:

```
var stats = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
for (var index in stats){
    for (var key in stats[index]) {
        console.log(stats[index][key]);
    }
}
```

or it is just simply a single object like:

```
stats = {}
```

then you can simply try:

```
for (var key in stats) {
    console.log(stats[key]);
}
```

so if it is an array-like object you have to different ways, first you can use [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-29):

```
stats = _.toArray(stats);
```

or if you don't want to use the [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-29) the other way is:

```
var stats2 = []
for (var key in stats) {
    stats2.push(key);
}
stats = stats2;
```

Comment: but this return too mutch names

Comment: It's not quite an array. It's an object, but the keys are numbers, as if it was a 1-based array.